# Sharing of dataset across users/apps when using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

As i understand there is public dataset(maintained by Google team) & private dataset(created by user/application).

Is it possible to share the private dataset created by 1 user for 1 app to be shared with another app using OAuth? Can access also be controlled like read-only or read-write access for that dataset?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 2):

All datasets have ACLs that allow them to be shared with other users. You can update the ACL of the dataset in the BigQuery UI or by using the dataset [PATCH API](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets/patch) if you are using the BigQueryAPI directly.